# How can I get rid of 'blank' versions of MS Office apps from the Start Menu?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, start-menu

I have a new Windows 10 computer (a Surface Go). I *think* it may have come with stub versions of Office. I've installed office and now my Start Menu looks like this:

[image]

Clicking on the blank entries doesn't launch the apps (in fact it does nothing). I've checked in

```
%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
```

Which only has the working versions (they actually start office) and

```
%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
```

Which doesn't have Office shortcuts at all.
And the only entries are the working versions. **How can I get rid of the blank MS Office entries from my Start Menu?**

Comment: I assume you can't right-click on these items?

Comment: @Ramhound I can. Right clicking a blank item and picking 'Uninstall' shows 'The app and it's related info will be uninstalled', clicking 'Uninstall' then doesn't do anything.

Comment: You may need to just clean office off of there and start over. See here about how to clean up Office when the regular uninstall doesn’t work: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/uninstall-office-from-a-pc-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8

Comment: You can also clear the residual items of the uninstall software via registry. https://www.wikihow.com/Delete-a-Program-Completely-by-Modifying-the-Registry-(Windows)